# What is the complexity of dist()?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance, distance-matrix

I used the `dist` function in R and I am wondering the time complexity of it.

I know that the hierarchical clustering has a `N^2*logN` time complexity. And hierarchical clustering is composed of two parts as below codes in R.

```
> d <- dist(as.matrix(mtcars))   # find distance matrix 
> hc <- hclust(d)                # apply hirarchical clustering 
> plot(hc)                       # plot the dendrogram
```

before applying hierarchical clustering, calculating the distance matrix is required. I think this takes `N^2` complexity?

Comment: The `hclust` function supposedly has O(n³) runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precisely, if matrix `X` has `N` rows `P` columns, the complexity of `dist(X)` is `3N(N-1)P/2`. This is computed by `N(N - 1)/2 * 3P`.

Explanation:

- There are `N(N - 1)/2` entries in the resulting distance matrix;
- Each entry is a dot product between two length `P` vectors (plus a square root), each involving `P` subtraction, `P` multiplication and `P` addition.

Comment: if `N`==`P`, then you mean it take `N^3`?

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, big O is all about when N gets very big and other parameters stay the same. So I think this is actually O(N^2).

Comment: Why Cluster algoritms like CAH or Gower has O(N^3) but they have N and P parameters?